# When Webpack/Typescript is built it is including the dependency types instead of just the library types

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have two libraries, `@org/core` and `@org/browser`. `browser` depends on the `core`, and core doesn't have any dependencies. When I build `browser` with webpack, the types from `core` are also built and placed in the dist folder. How can I exclude webpack/tsc from build those since the are not apart of the `browser` project?

When I run `tsc --showConfig` I get the following config:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "../.."
        "types": [
            "node"
        ],
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node10",
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "stripInternal": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/lib",
        "declarationDir": "./dist/types",
        "typeRoots": [
            "/vscode/org/packages/core/src/global.d.ts",       
            "/vscode/org/node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "../core/src/global.d.ts",
        "./src/index.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./dist/lib",
        "./dist/types"
    ]
}
```

The webpack config looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/lib'),
    filename: "browser.js",
    library: {
      type: 'umd',
      name: 'orgBrowser',
    }
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    fallback: {
      https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
      util: require.resolve('util/')
    }
  },
};
```

Once I build it, I get the following `dist` structure:

```
dist
  lib
    browser.js
  types
    browser/src
      index.d.ts
    core/src
      index.d.ts
```

However, this is what I want my dist to look like:

```
dist
  lib
    browser.js
  types
    index.d.ts
```